# dataframe.at[] adds new column instead of adding value

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a DataFrame:

```
  APPLICATION     COUNT K3_Code_Sender K3_Code_Receiver TWO
0    BCCTBL_2       0.0              0              287   x
1    BDLSMF01       0.0           9996                0   x
2    BEX00003       0.0            762                0   x
3    BEX01910  711762.0            762                0   x
4    BEX02955      60.0              0              287   x
5    BEX02970   12058.0            762              387   x
6    BEX03148     179.0              0                0   x
```

after following iterate and if statement(row[4] = row['TWO'], its like this just to check column position)

```
    for index, row in df_fin_k.iterrows():
        if row['K3_Code_Sender'] != '0' and row['K3_Code_Receiver'] != '0':
            df_fin_k.at[index, row[4]] = 2
        else:
            df_fin_k.at[index, row['TWO']] = 1
```

i get new column instead of seting values to TWO column:

```
  APPLICATION     COUNT K3_Code_Sender K3_Code_Receiver TWO    x
0    BCCTBL_2       0.0              0              287   x  1.0
1    BDLSMF01       0.0           9996                0   x  1.0
2    BEX00003       0.0            762                0   x  1.0
3    BEX01910  711762.0            762                0   x  1.0
4    BEX02955      60.0              0              287   x  1.0
5    BEX02970   12058.0            762              387   x  2.0
6    BEX03148     179.0              0                0   x  1.0
```

How to fix this so we would have:

```
  APPLICATION     COUNT K3_Code_Sender K3_Code_Receiver TWO
0    BCCTBL_2       0.0              0              287   1.0
1    BDLSMF01       0.0           9996                0   1.0
2    BEX00003       0.0            762                0   1.0
3    BEX01910  711762.0            762                0   1.0
4    BEX02955      60.0              0              287   1.0
5    BEX02970   12058.0            762              387   2.0
6    BEX03148     179.0              0                0   1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this once

```
for index, row in df_fin_k.iterrows():
    if row['K3_Code_Sender'] != '0' and row['K3_Code_Receiver'] != '0':
        df_fin_k.at[index, 'TWO'] = 2
    else:
        df_fin_k.at[index, 'TWO'] = 1
```

I Have replaced `df_fin_k.at[index, row['TWO']] = 1` with `df_fin_k.at[index, 'TWO'] = 1`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
for index , row in df.iterrows():
  if row['K3_Code_Sender'] + row['K3_Code_Receiver'] == 0:
    df['TWO'][index] = 2
  else: 
    df['TWO'][index] = 1
```

Comment: Nice first answer! Do you also get the desired output? It is a bit unclear when you say that you tried it without specifying any result!

Comment: @Aerows Thank you, it first gave "" me /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame ""

Comment: @Aerows but when I used df.head(6) it gave me the desired output